# Programmatically muting mobile in expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Is it possible to call a system level API and programmatically mute the volume of a mobile device?

Been reading through the Audio API docs but its not super clear if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling quite a lot and stuff:

It seems like there is no option with expo to get the device volume level, let alone to mute it.

The fact that expo doesn't give this option out-of-the-box, toghether with the fact that there are react-native libraries which give that option but require react-native "linking" (which expo does not seem to support), gives the feeling that it's not possibele with Expo to get the device's volume...

Comment: Thanks Shani. I've come to the same conclusion too. Instead I've achieved the sound muting with React Native as expo does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible actually this is how to go about it

To mute the audio

```
const MuteAudio = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
    if (result.isLoaded) {
      if (result.isPlaying === true) {
        sound.current.setIsMutedAsync(true)
    }
  } 
}catch (error) {}
```

}

To unmute the audio

```
const MuteAudio = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
    if (result.isLoaded) {
      if (result.isPlaying === true) {
        sound.current.setIsMutedAsync(false)
    }
  } 
}catch (error) {}
```

}